# Running parallel processes in older versions of Bash - version 3.2

Tags: bash

I am trying to run multiple process simultaneously with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r -p "Enter number of sessions: " pro_count
read -r -p "directory of files: " d

nodeb_job() {
    printf 'Connecting to %s\n' "$i"
    cd || exit
    if [ ! -d "$d" ]; then
        mkdir "$d"/log
    fi
    foo "$i" "$d"/"$i" >  "$d"/log/"$i"
    printf 'Done with %s\n' "$i"
}

j=0
for i in $(ls "$d"); do
    if (( j++ >= pro_count )); then
        wait -n
    fi
    nodeb_job &
done
wait
```

It is not working, because I have an older version of Bash:

```
user@dacc2:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I am a user on [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) 10, without [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel). Is there a way I can do this while still being able to specify the number of sessions from the prompt?

Comment: "It is not working". What error do you encounter?

Comment: @bishop `bash: wait: -n: invalid option`

Comment: The option was added because there was no good way to do this previously. Can you install a newer version of `bash` on your machine?

Comment: @Barmar I dont have administrative rights on the machine.

Comment: So install it in your own directory.

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not download GNU Parallel into your own dir? Or use `parallel --embed` to generate your script on another system? Is the reason covered on: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind a polling solution, one simple/quick-n-dirty approach based on counting the number of background `jobs` ...

```
j=0
for i in $(ls "$d"); do

    while [[ $(jobs | wc -l) -ge ${pro_count} ]]
    do
            sleep 2
    done

    nodeb_job &
done 
wait
```

Adjust the sleep time (2 seconds in this example) to whatever makes sense in your env.  For example, if the `nodeb_job()` calls are expected to take a few minutes, and you're not in a big hurry, you could do something like `sleep 30`. On the other hand, if the `nodeb_job()` calls are quick and/or you want a fast start to the next job, then perhaps `sleep 1` would be appropriate ... ?

Comment: This helped me since my env is using an older version of Bash.  Thanks!