# How can I limit the number of the same background process in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, background-process

Let's say I have a loop that runs something like the following a large number of times:

```
while *condition*
do
    {
    *cool stuff happens here, including running some programs*
    } &
done
```

As it is the system will quickly run out of resources so I want to set a limit (of say, 5 or 10) and then wait until they are done. How can I achieve this?

Comment: might be easier to use GNU parallel, depending on your goals.

Comment: If you don't mind a polling-type process using the `jobs` command: [running parallel process in older version of bash - version 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740746/running-parallel-process-in-older-version-of-bash-version-3-2)

Comment: So why not count the background processes, and if you read the limit, `wait` on them to finish?

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
maxcount=5
for ((i=0;i<10;++i)); do
    { sleep 0.$i; } &
    count=$((count + 1))
    if ((count++ > maxcount)); then
        wait -n
        count=$((count - 1))
    fi
done
# wait for the rest of processes
wait
```